# Which MySQL Charset.xml Contains utf8 & utf8mb4

Tags: mysql

Im wanting verify that my testing environment will be as close as possible to my production environment. In my test environment's DB I use `utf8mb4` as my charset. I decided to make sure that this character set would be available. I was not able to see the corresponding `xml` file for `utf8` or `utf8mb4` in my production environment. However when I decided to also check how the `xml` files look in my testing environment, they looked rather similar to the production environment. This leads me to believe that these character sets may be within another file. Which of these files (from test env `character_sets_dir`) contain the `utf8` and `utf8mb4` character sets?

[image]

Here are some of my variables which may provide more info (also from test env)

```
character_set_client = utf8mb4
character_set_connection = utf8mb4
character_set_database = utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem = binary
character_set_results = utf8mb4
character_set_server = latin1
character_set_system = utf8
```

I decided to open up the `index.xml` from above and found this entry. There is no entry for `utf8mb4` and no `.xml` for either.

```
<charset name="utf8">
  <family>Unicode</family>
  <description>UTF-8 Unicode</description>
  <alias>utf-8</alias>
  <collation name="utf8_general_ci" id="33">
   <flag>primary</flag>
   <flag>compiled</flag>
  </collation>
  <collation name="utf8_bin"        id="83">
    <flag>binary</flag>
    <flag>compiled</flag>
  </collation>
</charset>
```

**Partially Solved**

So I decided to use `SHOW CHARACTER SET` in both environments which both returned rows containing `utf8` and `utf8mb4`. This should indicate that both support what I need but I am still interested as to why the other places I looked do not contain info showing that `utf8mb4` is available.

Comment: What is this xml file you are taking about? What are you going to do with it?  Or are you just trying to check if your production environment supports utf8mb4?  What MySQL server version is your production environment?

Comment: @ysth both are currently 5.6. I am just wanting to confirm that both support utf8mb4

Comment: @ysth these are the `xml` files found at the `character_sets_dir`